# Collection GroupBy Aggregates without Stream API

Tags: java, arrays, collections, aggregate

I have a simple ArrayList with people's name and their ages (Person object).

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}

List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("john", 47));
personList.add(new Person("john", 35));
personList.add(new Person("john", 12));
personList.add(new Person("britney", 27));
personList.add(new Person("britney", 16));
```

The goal is to produce **ArrayList** with people, who has max age for every name, but without using Stream API. Similar to SQL's `SELECT name, max(AGE) FROM P GROUP BY name`:

> [Person("john", 47), Person("britney", 27)]

With Stream API I did it that way:

```
personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors
            .groupingBy(Person::getName,
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))))
            .values().stream()
            .map(s -> s.orElseGet(Person::new))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I doubt, whether I did it optimally without Stream API (the code is below).

**The question:** Is the code below an optimal way? If not, please describe yours with mentioning O-complexity.

**Second question:** Which O-complexity the solution with Stream API above has? Surprisingly, using functional approach I can't grasp it.

```
Map<String, Integer> personAgg = new HashMap<>();
personList.forEach(personAdd -> {
    var currentKey=personAdd.getName();
    var currentValue=personAdd.getAge();
    if (personAgg.containsKey(currentKey)) {
        if (personAgg.get(currentKey) < currentValue)
            personAgg.put(currentKey, currentValue);
    } else {
        personAgg.put(currentKey, currentValue);
    }
});

List<Person> personAggArray = new ArrayList<>();
personAgg.forEach((k,v) -> personAggArray.add(new Person(k,v)));
```

Comment: Are you talking about their time complexity when you say "optimal"? They are both O(n).

Comment: Yes, I used the word optimal in the meaning of complexity. Sorry for unclearness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of doing this has to be at least O(n), where n is the number of elements in `personList`. To find the max age of each person, you have to check *every* person.

There is very little to no time complexity guarantees on stream operations, so here I will assume the OpenJDK 17 implementation which I have on my machine. That said, it's hard to imagine anyone would write a non-optimal implementation.

Your solution using streams is O(n). Each element is processed first by the `groupingBy` collector to be put in one of the groups, then gets consumed by the `maxBy` collector, which operates on each group. The things that both collectors do are done in constant time. `groupingBy` just checks if it matches any existing group (this is done by a `HashMap` lookup), and `maxBy` compares it with the current max using the comparator provided.

Your solution not using streams is also O(n) - you do a bunch of constant time things (reading and writing to `personAgg`) for each element in `personList`. So it is optimal as far as time complexity is concerned.

Note that you could also rewrite the loop body to just one call to `compute`:

```
for (var person: personList) {
    personAgg.compute(
        person.getMame(),
        (k, v) -> Math.max(
            Objects.requireNonNullElse(v, Integer.MIN_VALUE),
            person.getAge()
        )
    );
}
```

Of course, this only avoids accessing the map multiple times, and change the time complexity.

Comment: Or `for (var person: personList) { personAgg.merge(person.getName(), person.getAge(), Math::max); }` By the way, the OP never created new `Person` instances in the original code. The supplier `Person::new` was the fallback for a case that never happens here.

Comment: With original code, I mean the Stream solution. To do the same with a loop, one could use `var personAgg = new HashMap<String, Person>(); for (var person: personList) { personAgg.merge(person.getName(), Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))); } var resultList = new ArrayList<>(personAgg.values());`

Comment: @Holger thanks. I must have thought the `personAgg.forEach(…)` like was part of the stream code too.

Comment: In the OP’s second variant, it is. This variant creates a temporary `Map<String, Integer>` to create the intended `List<Person>` with new `Person` instances. In contrast, the Stream variant creates a temporary `Map<String, Person>` with the original `Person` instances and transfers them to the result `List`. My first comment shows a simplification of the OP’s second variant/your answer which would requires the `forEach` as well, to create the final `List`. My second comment is like the OP’s first variant, passing the original `Person` instances to the result `List`.